# HTML/CSS three stacked/offset images

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am having trouble with stacking images in HTML/CSS for some reason. I have three slides, stacked on top of each other, slightly offset so that they peak out from under one another, bottom-to-top. The animation I am using should allow them to slide over to the right when I hover on the edge that is "peaking out." It works perfectly with two images, but for some reason, when I added a third to the pile, the animation for the bottom two stopped working. NO CLUE why this won't work.

Here is the code:

```css
#containerContainer {
  position: relative;
}
#instashContainer,
#wisdomCotainer,
#visContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 744px;
  width: 1860px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#instashContainer img,
#wisdomContainer img,
#visContainer img {
  opacity: .7;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: translate3d(-1600px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
}
#instashContainer img:hover,
#wisdomContainer img:hover,
#visContainer img:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="containerContainer">


  <!--Inspiration Slidepage-->
  <div id="instashContainer">
    <img src="instash_slidepage.jpg" height=744 width=1820>
    </img>
  </div>

  <!--Wisdom Slidepage-->
  <div id="wisdomContainer">
    <img src="wisdom_slidepage.jpg" height=744 width=1780>
    </img>
  </div>

  <!--Visualization Slidepage-->
  <div id="visContainer">
    <img src="visualization_slidepage.jpg" height=744 width=1740>
    </img>
  </div>


</div>
```

When I add the third image, on top of the other two, the animation for the other two stops working, but the animation for the top image works (i.e. it slides to the right). When I remove the top image, but change nothing else, the animation for the other two works again.

Why? Also, how can I add this third image without impacting the animation of the other two images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

- you have a typo here: `#wisdomCotainer`, should be`#wisdomContainer`

#### Notes

- don't use HTML tags `width`/`height`, use instead CSS
- `<img>` tag are self-closed tags, therefore don't need `</img>`
- and you can simplify your CSS in this case by using the direct child selector `>`

```css
#containerContainer {
  position: relative;
}
#containerContainer > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 744px;
  width: 1860px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#containerContainer > div img {
  opacity: .7;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: translate3d(-1600px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  height: 744px;
  width: 1820px;
}
#containerContainer > div img:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="containerContainer">
  <!--Inspiration Slidepage-->
  <div id="instashContainer">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1280/744" />
  </div>
  <!--Wisdom Slidepage-->
  <div id="wisdomContainer">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1280/744" />
  </div>
  <!--Visualization Slidepage-->
  <div id="visContainer">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1280/744" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was definitely part of the problem.I also had the containers stacked on top of one another, so the bottom two couldn't be hovered over.

Comment: Simplifying was the key, both the HTML and the CSS. I changed it to only have one container `<div>` with all three `<img>`  inside it, but adjusted the positions of the `<img>` to be offset from one another. Now when I hover over an `<img>` it animates perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo error here :

```
#instashContainer, #wisdomCotainer, #visContainer {
}
```

Should be `#wisdomContainer` instead.